# React Router v4 - active link issue

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router

I am having an issue with active link. 
I need to create few sub Routes and keep active styling on "parent" Route. How can I achieve that?

I am using withRouter for Routing purposes. 
Let say I have main Navigation with 3 "parent" Routes - `/login | /register /profile`.

```
 render () {
    return (
      <div className='grid'>
        <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
        <Route path='/login' component={LoginForm} />
        <Route path='/register' component={RegisterForm} />
        <PrivateRoute path='/profile' component={PersonalDetails} />
        <PrivateRoute path='/profile/delete-account' component={DeleteAccount} />
        <PrivateRoute path='/profile/payments' component={Payments} />
        <PrivateRoute path='/profile/food-preferences' component={FoodPreferences} />
      </div>
    );
}
```

Inside Component which is rendering on '/profile' route there is additional navigation with links to `'/profile/delete-account/'`, `'/profile/payments'`, `'profile/food-preferences'`.

```
static getProfileRoutes () {
    return profileRoutes.map(route => (
      <NavLink to={route.path} activeClassName='active-profile' className='profile-navigation-button' key={route.path}>
        <li className='profile-navigation-label'>{route.name}</li>
      </NavLink>
    ));
}
```

Unfortunately when I navigate to one of "child" routes, active styling from button in `SideBar` which navigates to `'/profile'` is lost. How can I prevent it? Fix it?

```
static getSideBarRoutes () {
    return sideBarRoutes.map(route => (
      <NavLink className='navigation-button' key={route.path} to={route.path}>
        <li className='navigation-item'>
          <div className={route.icon} />
          {route.name}
        </li>
      </NavLink>)
    );
}
```

Routing is working perfectly fine - its just problem with `active` class lost on `Sidebar`

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: how do u navigate to parent routes? if you are using exact there then that's a issue.

Comment: Can you explain? ( I just paste SideBar Navigation code )

Comment: You are not using it, so it's not a problem. hmm.. when you click on "child" navigation link do you get in browser /parent/child route name?

Comment: yes, there is full route name in browser. I am using "exact" only in default route which is "/"

Comment: try some workaround. In component where you create "parent" navigation make something like this. `if (props.location.pathname.indexOf(props.route) !== -1) {
    // here you can set parent active class if route contain parentRouteName in it.
  }`

Comment: I will give it a try, thanks

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
const navigation = (props) => {
  let styleClass= "not-active-class";
  if (props.location.pathname.indexOf(props.route) !== -1) {
    // checking if parent route is contained in route and setting active class
    styleClass= "active-class";
  }

  return (
    <NavLink
      to={props.route}
      activeClassName={styleClass} >
      <p>{props.route}</p>
    </NavLink>
  );
}
```

Comment: I will try this solution and I will get back to you. Thanks a lot for your participation.